# How to check if a list of one numpy array contains another numpy array

Tags: list, numpy

For example, I want, given the list
`given_list = [np.array([1,44,21,2])]`
Check if this list contains another numpy array, for example `np.array([21,4,1,21])`

I tried this but it checks if each element of the numpy array is the equal to the new numpy array

```
import numpy as np
given_list = [np.array([1,44,21,2])]
new_elem = np.array([21,4,1,21])

print([new_elem==elem for elem in given_list])
```

I would like to receive '[False]', but instead I get '[array([False, False, False, False])]'.

I don't understand why `given_list` is identified as a numpy array and not as a list of one numpy array.

Comment: numpy is too smart, if you have a `==` operator it will compare by elements. I just executed `print(np.ones(4) == np.arange(4))` and it gives `[False  True False False]`

Comment: You are iterating on `given_list` and comparing arrays.  Nothing is treating the list as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
[np.array_equal(new_elem, elem) for elem in given_list]
```

or [`numpy.allclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) if you want to have some tolerance:

```
[np.allclose(new_elem, elem) for elem in given_list]
```

output: `[False]`

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that your arrays have the same length you can do this task without cycling the elements of `given_list`. For example:

```
given_list = [np.array([1,44,21,2]), np.array([21,4,1,21])]
new_elem = np.array([21,4,1,21])

(np.array(given_list)==new_elem).all(axis=1) #array([False,  True])
```

Otherwise, you can use the @mozway 's `[np.array_equal(new_elem, elem) for elem in given_list]`